# Replacing subqueries with JOIN or WITH

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2008-r2, subquery

From [this article](http://www.componentworkshop.com/blog/2009/06/23/advanced-sql-server-removing-sub-queries-using-with-sql-server-20052008), the author decides to use `WITH` to replace subqueries used of this manner:

```
SELECT c.CategoryName, p.ProductName, p.UnitPrice
    FROM Categories c
    INNER JOIN (SELECT CategoryId, MAX(UnitPrice) AS MaxPrice
        FROM Products GROUP BY CategoryId) maxprice
        ON maxprice.CategoryId = c.CategoryId
    INNER JOIN Products p
        ON p.CategoryId = c.CategoryId
            AND p.UnitPrice = maxprice.MaxPrice
    ORDER BY MaxPrice DESC
```

Here is the author's resulting query:

```
WITH MostExpensiveProducts (CategoryId, MaxUnitPrice) AS
(
    SELECT CategoryId, MAX(UnitPrice)
        FROM Products
        GROUP BY CategoryId
)
SELECT c.CategoryName, p.ProductName, p.UnitPrice
    FROM Categories c
    INNER JOIN MostExpensiveProducts mep
        ON mep.CategoryId = c.CategoryId
    INNER JOIN Products p
        ON p.CategoryId = mep.CategoryId
            AND p.UnitPrice = mep.MaxUnitPrice
    ORDER BY mep.MaxUnitPrice DESC;
```

Now this article is over 6 years old but it is still relevant to me because I am using SQL Server 2008. However, most of my search results revolving around replacing subqueries involve `JOINS`. This is confusing for me because the subqueries here are already within `INNER JOINs`.

Do this solution using `WITH` still hold weight today? Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: you are not really removing the subquery, just using a CTE, which for a lot of people improve *readability*

Comment: @Lamak that's what i thought.. now is there an actual solution for replacing this type of subquery?

Comment: What would you consider an actual solution?   What would be different about it than this one?   I'm not clear on what your goal is.

Comment: @TabAlleman sorry for the lack of clarity. regarding the solution involving `WITH`, Lamak said its not really removing the subquery.. so is there a solution for removing this subquery that doesn't involve `WITH`?

Answer (score 2):

Preamble:

- Joins are no bad thing per se
- The use of WITH in this example is purely for readability (see [WITH-Clause](https://modern-sql.com/feature/with) and [Literate SQL](https://modern-sql.com/use-case/literate-sql)). However, I personally consider this query too little to apply this techniques — but it's just an example to demo it.

Having said that, I find the example pretty wired: it lists the most expensive products per category (which can be more then one in case the more products in a category having the same price).

Having said that, there is still one join that is not necessary anymore: the join of `Products` table to the result of the `WITH` clause (not the join on `p.UnitPrice = mep.MaxUnitPrice`. When I see this, it's usually a bug. I'll assume that now.

If the intention is to show the most expensive product per category (only one in case of ties), the solution posted by @Tab Alleman while I was writing is OK. If you really need to list multiple rows in case of ties, you would use `RANK()` (or `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` in @Tab Alleman's solution.

Another approach using more modern SQL to solve this requirement is to use `LATERAL`: this allows you to apply a per-category `TOP` (or `LIMIT` or `FETCH FIRST ... ROWS ONLY` clause). In SQL Server, that's actually called `CROSS APPLY` (`LATERAL` is the keyword the SQL Standard and other databases use).

```
SELECT c.CategoryName, p.ProductName, p.UnitPrice
  FROM Categories c
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ProductName, UnitPrice
                FROM Products
               WHERE Products.Category = c.CategoryId
               ORDER BY UnitPrice DESC) p
```

(I did not run this query, mistakes are unintentional ;) In case of ties, it's not specified which of the two equally-priced products shows up.

The performance of the `OVER` solution and the `LATERAL`/`APPLY` solution could vary (which is better depends on the data and indexes you have).

Tthe `LATERAL`/`APPLY` solution can also deliver all products in case of a tie. The SQL standard allows the `FETCH FIRST ... ROWS ONLY` to have a `WITH TIES` modifier. Apperently, SQL Servers has `TOP 1 WITH TIES` too ([source](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/480781/SQL-Server-TOP-WITH-TIES-A-Beauty-of-TSQL)).

If you'd like to learn more about useful SQL features you might not yet know, have a look at these slides: https://modern-sql.com/slides

Answer (score 1):

This solution does use a CTE, but it uses ROW_NUMBER() rather than a subquery to get the most expensive product in each category, and therefore avoids joining to products twice:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT CategoryId, ProductId, UnitPrice,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryId ORDER BY UnitPrice DESC) rn
  FROM Products
)
SELECT CategoryId, ProductId, UnitPrice
FROM cte
WHERE rn=1
ORDER BY UnitPrice DESC
```